# How to make DD make a copy of my iPod's harddrive into my computer?

Tags: ssh, hard-drive, dd

I'm trying to do [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222714/is-it-possible-to-use-dd-to-obtain-splited-images-from-a-hard-drive), I'm sure you don't wanna read all that then I'll make a resume on it: A file was accidentally deleted on a iPod4, I need to recover it and I've been able to do all the process through SSH and DD.

I was using this command:

```
root@g1:/home/gustav# ssh root@192.168.1.101 dd if=/dev/rdisk0s2s1 bs=1M | dd of=iphone-use2.img
root@192.168.1.101's password: 
Write failed: Broken pipe
4113088+0 records in
4113088+0 records out
2105901056 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 51107.2 s, 41.2 kB/s
```

And then I was having this error - I had the error twice, the first time I had it I could make a ISO file of ~11GB, the second time I've made a file of ~2GB. I presume the dd process can stop due to unknown reasons then I had the [idea of using the DD to make splits of the iPod's harddrive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222714/is-it-possible-to-use-dd-to-obtain-splited-images-from-a-hard-drive).

Then I've started to use these commands:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.101 dd if=/dev/rdisk0s2s1 of=iphone1.img bs=1M count=1024
ssh root@192.168.1.101 dd if=/dev/rdisk0s2s1 skip=1024 of=iphone1.img bs=1M count=1024
...
```

The problem now is: When I was using the first command, the DD was copying the ISO file to my computer, with this second command it's copying the ISO file to the iPod's harddrive, how can I specify **where** the output file is going? I want it copied to my computer, I'm aware that it may involve some alteration on the `of` argument but I don't know how to do it, can you help me?

Also, why the first command make a copy of the iPod's disk to my computer drive and the second make a copy of my iPod's disk to itself, if the `of` argument is similar on both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your SSH session is cutting out. I've expirienced a similar problem in a different situation. Try adding this line to your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file on your PC:

```
ServerAliveInterval 120
```

Give it a try and see if that prevents your Broken Pipe errors.

As for your command your missing something. It should be:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.101 dd if=/dev/rdisk0s2s1 bs=1M count=1024 | dd of=iphone1.img
```

You forgot to pipe the `dd` output to your PC.

Comment: This won't solve the problem, even doing that I can have problems with router, power, etc. I need to find a definitive way for doing it, and I guess this way is through the splitted images.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira WiFi reliability isn't a real problem. Hasn't ever stopped me from copying large files between devices before. Anyway I've addressed your `dd` issue as well. Check my edited Answer.

Comment: Yeah, but here the power is a little unstable. The `|` means "pipe out of the device"?

Comment: The `|` symbol means "pipe output of this to input of that" so basically the command is this: "ssh connect to iPod, use dd to read /dev/rdisk0s2s1, pipe output of ssh command(reading of disk) to dd and write data to file 'iphone1.img'"

Comment: Everybody has lapses :)

Comment: The skip option is also behind the `|` right?

Comment: @GustavoBandeira No, that option should be before the `|` as it pertains to reading the drive and not writing.

Comment: I'm trying to use [this list of commands](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtJEkRZxOJUpdEJTLTBvV1U3UTltVHNmY2tiaW5feGc). But nothing happens, hint?

Comment: @GustavoBandeira Why is the IP different after the first two commands? Also make sure these commands are being run on your PC not your iPod. The IP needs to be the current LAN IP of the iPod.

Comment: This is the iPod's IP now.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira Where exactly are you getting a problem? Do you get an error when you try to run one of the commands?

Comment: Nope, when I enter the command, nothing happens

Comment: @GustavoBandeira By nothing happening do you mean you get an endlessly Blinking Cursor or that you get bumped back to the command-line without an error? If it's the first option then it's working fine. `dd` doesn't provide any output until after it's finished copying.